# Fast changing multiple columns by condition in R using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset, where each individual is identified by an unique "code" variable. But there are some duplicates (=same code), which have slightly different values in other columns. I would like to change values of one of those duplicates of some columns to NA. I would like to select the duplicit based on conditions in different columns.

For example if `code == "B"` and `col4 == 300`, all columns from `col2` to `col30` should have value `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  code = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D"),
  col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
  col2 = c(10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40),
  col3 = c("X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "W", "W"),
  col4 = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600),
  col5 = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000),
  col30 = c("X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "W", "W")
)
```

EDIT:
The goal state would be:

```
  code   col1  col2 col3   col4  col5 col30
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 A         1    10 X       100  1000 X    
2 B         2    20 Y       200  2000 Y    
3 B         3    NA NA       NA    NA NA   
4 C         3    30 Z       400  4000 Z    
5 D         4    40 W       500  5000 W    
6 D         4    40 W       600  6000 W
```

I have this solution:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(col2:col30), ~ifelse(code == "B" & col1 == 3, NA, .)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

It works, but it is quite slow for larger dataframes. There must be a faster way. Thank you.

I tried using `case_match`, but it did not helped. And using `mutate(across(col2:col30)` does not seem to work with `:` selector.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  So is the logic just if code = "B" and col1 = 3 it should be NA?

Comment: if so a base approach is:  `df[df$code == "B" & df$col1 == 3, -c(1,2)] <- NA`

Comment: In your question you say "But there are some duplicates, which are slightly different" (so not duplicates...) and "I would like to select the duplicit based on conditions in different columns." but you don't say what the conditions are.  If you can either define the logic to follow or give a full desired outcome for your example it would help.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Hi, thank you for your comment, I added an example and a goal state: For example if code == "B" and col4 == 300, all columns from col2 to col30 should have value NA. Thank you, I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code with `sapply`

```r
cbind(df[-c(3,4,5,6,7)],
      sapply(df[c(3,5,6)],\(x) ifelse(duplicated(x),NA,x)),
      sapply(df[c(4,7)],\(x) ifelse(duplicated(x),NA_character_, trimws(paste0(x))))
      )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  code col1 col2 col4 col5 col3 col30
1    A    1   10  100 1000    X     X
2    B    2   20  200 2000    Y     Y
3    B    3   NA  300 3000 <NA>  <NA>
4    C    3   30  400 4000    Z     Z
5    D    4   40  500 5000    W     W
6    D    4   NA  600 6000 <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: I am intrigued by this approach - how did you divine this logic from the OP?  Is the problem familiar of have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: sorry I did not understand when you say `OP`, with regard to the question I assumed it for all duplicated not only for col1==3

Comment: OP just referring to Original Poster (i.e. the question post)

Comment: ok thank you, I am not sure of the exact answer of the OP either so will have to wait and see for his response

Comment: I added more explanation to the original post. Sorry for unclarity, I meant duplications by code variable.